# Returning repeating number of rows in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table like this:

```
|---------|-----|
| Name    | Qty |
|---------|-----|
| Joe     | 3   |
| Bill    | 2   |
| Mike    | 4   |
|---------|-----|
```

I am trying to create a `SELECT` statement that will return this:

```
|--------|
| Name   |
|--------|
| Joe    |
| Joe    |
| Joe    |
| Bill   |
| Bill   |
| Mike   |
| Mike   |
| Mike   |
| Mike   |
|--------|
```

Basically, whatever the `Qty` field is set to is how many times the `Name` is returned. I found a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664903/how-can-i-return-multiple-identical-rows-based-on-a-quantity-field-in-the-row-it), but this question is for Oracle and I'm using SQL Server. I also would prefer to do this in a `SELECT` statement (because it'll later be used in a view) rather than having to use temp tables or cursors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a recursive cte to do this

**[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/07dda/1)**

```
;with cte
as
(select * from table1
union all
select name, qty - 1
from cte
where qty - 1 > 0
)

select name from cte
order by name
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with a tally or numbers table also. The problem with a recursive cte like that is that it is really a row by row process under the hood. This approach is 100% set based.

```
create table #table1
(
    Name varchar(10),
    Qty int
);

insert #table1
select 'Joe', 3 union all
select 'Bill', 2 union all
select 'Mike', 4;

WITH
    E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
    Numbers(N) AS 
    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E1
    )

select *
from #table1 t
join numbers n on n.N <= t.Qty

drop table #table1
```